# WCF 4: Fileless Activation Fails On XP (IIS 5) that has SSL port enabled

Tags: wcf, ssl, .net-4.0, activation

I have a service being hosted in IIS on XP via fileless activation.   The service starts fine when there is no SSL port enabled for IIS but when the SSL port is enabled, I get the error message:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SkillsPrototype.Web/services/Linkage.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://rcollet.hsb-corp.hsb.com/SkillsPrototype.Web/Services/Linkage.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. . ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://rcollet.hsb-corp.hsb.com/SkillsPrototype.Web/Services/Linkage.svc'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

My service model configuration is

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
           <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
      <serviceActivations>
        <clear/>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" service="SkillsPrototype.ServiceModel.Linkage" relativeAddress="~/Services/Linkage.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When you look in the svclog file, there two base addresses that are returned when SSL is enabled, one for http and one for https.  I suspect that this is part of the issue but I am not sure how to resolve it.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>524333</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-06-16T17:40:55.8168605Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{95927f9a-fa90-46f4-af8b-721322a87aaa}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="aspnet_wp" ProcessID="1888" ThreadID="5" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>RCOLLET</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBaseAddresses.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>ServiceHost base addresses.</Description>
          <AppDomain>/LM/w3svc/1/ROOT/SkillsPrototype.Web-1-129211836532542949</AppDomain>
          <Source>System.ServiceModel.WebScriptServiceHost/49153359</Source>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/CollectionTraceRecord">
            <BaseAddresses>
              <Address>http://rcollet.hsb-corp.hsb.com/SkillsPrototype.Web/Services/Linkage.svc</Address>
              <Address>https://rcollet.hsb-corp.hsb.com/SkillsPrototype.Web/Services/Linkage.svc</Address>
            </BaseAddresses>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

I can't post the full service log due to character limits on the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It figures after spending hours on this I resolve the issue shortly after posting.

It appears that the issue is related to using WebScriptServiceHostFactory.  Instead I created a service entry with a kind attribute and now it works.

Here is the corrected configuration

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>      
    </standardEndpoints>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <!--Default settings for the webHttpBinding-->
        <binding>
           <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service name="SkillsPrototype.ServiceModel.Linkage">
        <endpoint
          kind="webScriptEndpoint"
          contract="SkillsPrototype.ServiceModel.ILinkage"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
      <serviceActivations>
        <clear/>
        <add service="SkillsPrototype.ServiceModel.Linkage" relativeAddress="~/Services/Linkage.svc"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```